# PHP convert string of numbers into a date

Tags: php, regex

I am basically trying to determine a warranty date based on serial numbers being uploaded to our system.

For instance, a serial number could be something like:
`217A111111111` where `17` from the `217` is the year so 2017. and then the 4th digit is the month where Jan-Sep is 1-9 and then October is `A`, November is `B` and December is `C`

I basically need to be able to pull `17A` and make it = `2017-10-01` or `171` = `2017-01-01`

I know I would use regex for this but I am unsure of how to make it check whether the 4th digit is a number or a letter, if letter `A`, `B` or `C` then it is October, November or December, else if 1-9 then Jan-Sep.

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: Use substring instead

Comment: You cannot somehow train a regular expression to do a conversion of some character into some meaning. You need a dictionary for that, for the months in this case.

Comment: Couldn't I theoretically do something like:  `$sn=217A111111111; $sn_year=substr($sn,1,10); $sn_month=substr($sn,3,9); if ($sn_month=="A"){ $sn_month="10"};` something along those lines? Sorry for bad formating

Comment: Yep, this method worked. Thank you @FelippeDuarte

Answer (score 2):

This should be working:

```
$serialnr = '217A111111111';
$month = hexdec($serialnr[3]);
$date = new \DateTime('20' . $serialnr[1] . $serialnr[2] . '-' . $month . '-01');
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/WEktB)

Comment: Thanks @vp_arth for spotting the missing bracket and adding the demo

Answer (score 1):

If you know that what you are looking for is always at 4 place in your string,  you can simple do:

```
hexdec(substr($str,3,1))
```

which returns "9" for "9", "10" for "a", "11" for "b" ... etc.

Knowing number you can obtain month however you want.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = '217A111111111';

const truncated = input.substr(1, 3)

let year = 2000+parseInt(truncated.substr(0, 2))
let month = parseInt('0x'+truncated.substr(2, 1)); // 0x prefix is for hexadecimal

console.log(year, month, new Date(`${year}-${month}-01`))
```

Comment: 'm sorry, miss a php tag